# Tiled option selection in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, jetpack

How to design a tiled option selection in Jetpack compose? It's fine if you cannot share the code - looking for which component will allow me to achieve this behavior. I am refraining from using the word "dropdown" because it does not dropdown, rather it shows options on the screen to the right of the component when it is clicked.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Off the cuff, that seems like a `LazyColumn()` in its own `Window`.